# Form always submits even when not validated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I want to build a form that only submits after validation (using ajax, for both the validation and the submit).

From what I have now, it always submits. It shows the messages that the fields are not correct, but it still inserts empty fields into the database.

Any idea on how to insert it after validation?

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div id="wrap">
<table>
<td>
    <form name="form">
        <tr>
        <p class="names">Voornaam:</p> <p><input type="text" name="voornaam" id="voornaam"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <p class="names">Achternaam:</p> <p><input type="text" name="achternaam" id="achternaam"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <p class="names">Telefoonnummer:</p> <p><input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" id="telefoonnummer"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <p class="names">Emailadres:</p> <p><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <input class="knop" type="submit" name="insert" value="Opsturen" id="insert">
        </tr>
    </form>
</td>
</table>
<br>
<div id="berichten">

</div>

<script>
var validator = new FormValidator('form', [{
    name: 'voornaam',
    display: 'Voornaam',    
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'achternaam',
    display: 'achternaam', 
    rules: 'required'
},{
    name: 'telefoonnummer',
    display: 'telefoon', 
    rules: 'required|numeric'
},{
    name: 'email',
    display: 'email', 
    rules: 'required|valid_email'
}], function(errors, event) {
    var berichten = document.getElementById('berichten');

    berichten.innerHTML = '';

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; i++) {
            berichten.innerHTML += errors[i].message + '<br>';
        }

    }

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#insert').click(function(){
            var voornaam = $('#voornaam').val();
            var achternaam = $('#achternaam').val();
            var telefoonnummer = $('#telefoonnummer').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();

            $.post('action.php',{action: "submit", voornaam:voornaam, achternaam:achternaam, telefoonnummer:telefoonnummer, email:email},function(res){
                $('#result').html(res);
            });
            document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = 'Verstuurd!';   
        });

    });
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: prevent default behaviour of submit click. Then submit FORM manually if FORM is valid. But as you are using a plugin which i don't know, i couldn't help you more

Comment: You really shouldn't depend on JS to validate, **especially** for database purposes. Use a server-side method in addition to using JS.

Comment: Yeah I know it's easier with PHP, but I don't want it to refresh, so it has to be done with ajax.

Comment: and, more **reliable** ;-) keep that in mind.

Comment: Could be, but again, I don't want it to refresh the page when it submits.

Answer (score 2):

Its because, your `submit` button works even if we have javascript validations has errors.

You should add a `return false` in the function to stop it submitting the form.

Also, error count should also be considered.

So, the updated code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#insert').click(function(){
                var voornaam = $('#voornaam').val();
                var achternaam = $('#achternaam').val();
                var telefoonnummer = $('#telefoonnummer').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();


if (errors.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; i++) {
                berichten.innerHTML += errors[i].message + '<br>';
    return false;
            }
}                $.post('action.php',{action: "submit", voornaam:voornaam, achternaam:achternaam, telefoonnummer:telefoonnummer, email:email},function(res){
                    $('#result').html(res);
                });
                document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = 'Verstuurd!';
      return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: It still always submits the form when I add that.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

add:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Within your click function.

```
$(function(){
    $('#insert').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: It shows the error messages when I add that, but it still inserts into the database.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using type="submit" use type="button" i think this will solve your problem.....

Comment: It also submits alwways when I change that.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `return false;` statement

```
if (errors.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; i++) {
    berichten.innerHTML += errors[i].message + '<br>';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That still submits the form. I want it to submit after the validation.